# How to catch concurrency exception for a shared local database (SQL Server Compact | .sdf) in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce, local-database

I am writing a programm that allows two users to access the same local database (.sdf) in a shared folder. The database consists of tasks for the employee. One user (Master) adds and edits those tasks, the other one (Slave) marks them as done/undone and updates the list.

The two of them should be allowed to work simultaneously. I.e. Master adds a new task, Slave finishes one task, updates the list and finds the new one immediately.

When a database query is executed an instance of a module is created that opens the database, executes the SQL-query (Select, Update, Delete, ...) and closes it. This is how the VB module looks like:

```
Public Sub ExecQuery(Query As String)
        Try
            SQLCon.Open()
            SQLCmd = New SqlCeCommand(Query, SQLCon) 'Create SQL command

            ' Load Parameters into SQL Command
            Params.ForEach(Sub(x) SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(x))
            Params.Clear() ' Clear Parameter List

            ' Execute Command, Fill Dataset and close database
            SQLDS = New DataSet
            SQLCon.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
             Exception = ex.Message

        End Try

        If SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then SQLCon.Close()
End Sub
```

If have to admit, that I took the code-snippet from a tutorial.

Now an update of the DataGridView would look like this:

```
Public Sub GetEntry()

        Dim ii As Integer = 0
        grdData.Rows.Clear() 'empty GridDataView

        SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Tasks)    
        grdData.Rows.Add(n)
        For Each r As DataRow In SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows
            grdData.Item(0, ii).Value = r(0)
            grdData.Item(1, ii).Value = r(1)
            grdData.Item(2, ii).Value = r(2)
            ' ...

            ii += 1
        Next

        If SQL.Exception <> "" Then
            MsgBox(SQL.Exception)
        End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that when Master and Slave both perform an SQL.ExecQuery(String) command, they are accessing the same .sdf which should not be possible, right? I expected something like "Cannot open database.sdf, as it is currently accessed by another user". I then would like to let the script wait for one second and retry. But instead I get "Error: Index out of range". So I assume, the code tries to read all entries but it can't.

Does anybody know how to catch this exception? I read about a

> Data.DBConcurrencyException

but I don't know if it's the thing I am looking for and how to use it.

Comment: "Index of of range" sounds like a bug in your code

Comment: The program works 100% fine. The error occurs when we trigger it, by simultaneously firing "Update" on both computers and thus forcing them to access the same database at the same time. I hoped it would catch the exception as a "concurrency error", but it doesn't....

Comment: If it's getting "Index out of range" then it's not "100% fine".  The bug has existed up to now and was only exposed by having multiple users at the same time.  What line of code is the exception occurring on?  The stack should tell you this.

Comment: It does not tell me the line of code when it happens. It says "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Column 1 not found". The error occurs in the GetEntry() procedure which I shared in my question.

The question is: why does it not find the data in the database when another user accesses the database as well and how can I avoid this.

Comment: Another thing I just realized: the error differs. Sometimes it complains that it cannot convert a data type, then it cannot acces a line and next time it cannot access a column. The code crashes when two parties access the same database and the error appears to be quasi-random, depending on the exact execution step of the code. 

So I guess it comes down to the question: how I can I check if a database is already open on another machine or analyzed by another process.